# Showing that product of proper functions are proper if and only if functions are proper

Tags: general-topology

let $f_1 : X_1 \to Y_1 $ and $f_2 : X_2 \to Y_2 $. I'm asked to show that

$$f_1 \times f_2 : X_1 \times X_2 \to Y_1 \times Y_2 $$ is proper if and only if $f_i$ are. But I couldn't think of a way to approach since I really couldn't figure out how $f_1 \times f_2$ is defined? Is it just the product of functions? If so, How can I define the inverse of this product? Say $U \subset Y_1 \times Y_2$ is compact, and if I assume the product is proper then does that mean $f_1^{-1} (U) \ f_2^{-1} (U)$ is compact?

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

The product $f_1\times f_2$ is defined by
$$
(f_1\times f_2)(x_1,x_2):=(f_1(x_1),f_2(x_2)).
$$

Given a subset $U$ of $Y_1\times Y_2$, the preimage (not inverse) is defined in the usual way. That is,
\begin{align*}
(f_1\times f_2)^{-1}(U) &:= \{(x_1,x_2)\in X_1\times X_2 \mid (f_1\times f_2)(x_1,x_2)\in U\} \\
&= \{(x_1,x_2)\in X_1\times X_2 \mid (f_1(x_1),f_2(x_2))\in U\}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Definition.  If f:X -> Y, g:S -> T, then
f×g:X×S -> Y×T, (x,y) -> ((f(x),g(y)).

Exercise:  show
$(f×g)^{-1}(A×B) = f(A)^{-1} × g(x)^{-1}$

Assume f×g is proper.
If compact K subset Y, pick some a with g(a) in T.
Then K×{g(a)} is compact, thus
$(f×g)^{-1}(K×{g(a)}) = f(K)^{-1} × g({a})^{-1}$ is compact.
Take the first projection to conclude f is proper.  Likewise g.

The other direction is not as easy.

Comment: The point is, not every compact subset of $Y_{1}\times Y_{2}$ is of the form $A\times B$ for compact sets $A$ and $B$, this makes the if part no easy.

Comment: @user284331.  If Y×T is Hausdorff and f×g is continuous, then that f×g is proper is as easy to show.